# point transfer to user bug laravel

Tags: php, laravel

the issue I'm having is when a user doesn't have point anyone and he chooses a user to transfer to the user point increase why the users that is tend to receive the point get deducted instead

the issue I am having is when a user pass points as minus ( -1  ) the (user transferring the point gets addition points ) if the user has no points I will like to stop user from making transfer

```
public function transferPoints(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'user_id' => 'required',
            'points' => [
                'nullable',
                function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
                    $current_points_check = Auth::user()->points;

                    if (!empty($current_points_check)) {
                        // we check if user is not exceeding his points limit
                        if ($value > $current_points_check) {
                            // fail the validation if user enters more points than he has
                            $fail('You tried to send invalid amount of' . $attribute);
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        ]);

        if ($validator->passes()) {

            // you update the points of the user

            //add the points to the other user
            User::find($request->user_id)->increment('points', $request->points);

            //decrement the points of the current user
            Auth::user()->decrement('points', $request->points);

            // redirect user
            return redirect()->back()->withMessage('Success!');
        }

        return back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }
```

Comment: Can you be more clear? what do you send for transferPoints(Request $request), what answer you expect and what is the result? I think what you saying is you have some trouble when you dont pass points as input, am I right?

Comment: the issue I am having is when I pass points as -10

Answer (score 1):

Based on source code increment and decrement implemented like this

```php
$this->{$column} = $this->{$column} + ($method == 'increment' ? $amount : $amount * -1);
```

lets assume current user has 0 points and want to donate (-10) points so we need to decrement (-10) points

It means at last we have

```php
$method = 'increment';
$this->{$column} = $this->{$column} + ($method == 'increment' ? 0 : -10 * -1);
```

finally you have

```php
$this->{$column} = $this->{$column} + 10;
```

so current user points equals to 0-(-10) = +10

Therefor we have 0+(-10) = -10 for guest user

That's why you get the opposite result

I am not sure why you want to let people to transfer negative points and I don't know about the purpose but you can validate them to have more than zero points.

```php
public function transferPoints(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'user_id' => 'required',
            'points' => [
                'nullable',
                function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
                    $current_points_check = Auth::user()->points;
                    if ($value <= 0) {
                            // fail the validation if user enters zero or negative point
                            $fail('You tried to send invalid amount of' . $attribute);
                    }
                    if (!empty($current_points_check)) {
                        // we check if user is not exceeding his points limit
                        if ($value > $current_points_check) {
                            // fail the validation if user enters more points than he has
                            $fail('You tried to send invalid amount of' . $attribute);
                        }
                    } 
                }
            ]
        ]);

        if ($validator->passes()) {

            // you update the points of the user

            //add the points to the other user
            User::find($request->user_id)->increment('points', $request->points);

            //decrement the points of the current user
            Auth::user()->decrement('points', $request->points);

            // redirect user
            return redirect()->back()->withMessage('Success!');
        }

        return back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }
```